# How to keep the colour of a logo visually the same on digital platforms and on print?

Tags: color, print-design, print-production, color-reproduction, color-management

The design is to be printed on product packagings and also to be on the client’s social media profiles. The goal is for their customers to see the same colour visually in both places.

When designing, I am looking at a digital screen, even if I use CMYK mode, it’s still a digital screen and it displays differently than print. What would be the best approach to this?

Comment: Use a hardware calibrator to make sure your screen shows what you think it shows.  But realistically there is nothing you can do about social media. Also not very important either. The important thing is that separate store batches match as you see them side by side.

Answer (score 3):

> *The goal is for their customers to see the same colour visually in both places.*

The goal is unrealistic, because you can never match a color to look the same across all the customers' devices. People will have iPhone's, Samsung's and Nokia's, then some will have damaged screens and some will have a yellow filter applied. Also you have no way of controlling the levels of system contrast & brightness in every device, which again will impact colors.

Same goes for computers and laptops, every brand will have different color variations, and even between different products of the same brand.

Also, nobody in the history of design ever achieved flawless matching between RGB and CMYK items, and you have technical arguments:

- [RGB and CMYK: Why both?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7815/rgb-and-cmyk-why-both)
- [Relationship between onscreen/printed CMYK and RGB](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79905/relationship-between-onscreen-printed-cmyk-and-rgb)
- [What is the difference between CMYK and RGB? Are there other color spaces I should know?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60/what-is-the-difference-between-cmyk-and-rgb-are-there-other-color-spaces-i-shou)

> *What would be the best approach to this?*

You can do what every brand out there does: always use the same RGB scheme for digital, and the same CMYK / Pantone scheme for print.